# passing arguments with postback to page

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

iv'e got an aspx page with some user controls , all of which contain a checkbox .

the checkbox is checked when the user control is added to the page.
the checkbox is set to auto post back

what i need is for when the auto post back occurs the user control will be gone.

first of all the way i load my user controls :
i load them as rows in a table and give their ID values the value of an entity that they represent

```
   private void Load_Products(List<AppProduct> user_products)
    {
        HtmlTableRow row = null;
        foreach(AppProduct p in user_products)
        {
            row = new HtmlTableRow();
            tbl_products.Rows.Add(row);

            CartProduct prd = (CartProduct)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/CartProduct.ascx");

            prd.Title = p.Title;
            prd.Price = p.Price.ToString();
            prd.Pid = p.Pid.ToString();
            prd.ID = p.Pid.ToString();
            prd.State = 2;

            prd.Product_Checked += new EventHandler(prd_Product_Checked);

            HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(prd);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
    }
```

the CartProduct UserControl represents the AppProduct Entity

now the way i removed the product (usercontrol) was by removing it from the list as follows :

```
    void prd_Product_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      // this removes the product from the same list that the load products function gets
           ProductChangedEventArgs args = (ProductChangedEventArgs)e;
           cart.RemoveProduct(uid, args.Pid);                        
           Response.Redirect("~/Pages/cart.aspx");  
    }
```

now this works , but it seems wrong to have to postback and then redirect again in order to take affect the removal from the list occur's on the post back , but takes affect 
only on the next page load, when the list is re-loaded .
if i could some how remove the item from the list during the page load of the post back
with out having to re-direct again.

any ideas how i could skip the redirect ?
i thought of maybe sending arguments with  the postback but i don't know if that's even possible , cause then i could send the product id and remove it from the list before Load_Products is called .

thanks in advance 
eran.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Redirect why don't you simply call Load_Products again with the updated list of products?

Comment: o'k that's a good idea , but there's a problem by doing that 
even if i call Load_Products and it loads all the remaining products in my list the non-refreshed page still shows the earlier occurrences  of the user controls loaded in the last page load .

Comment: @continue here :
lets say i got 2 user controls :

something1 something1_date [checked] 
something2 something2_date [checked] 

now ill remove something1 (uncheck him) from the list  , and call 
Load_Products the result would be 

something1 something1_date [un-checked] 
something2 something2_date [checked]
something2 something2_date [checked] 

it would add the items to the non-refreshed page.
the page doesn't know the list was altered it just loads user controls according to the list's content.

Comment: @eran: you are adding the CartProduct controls to tbl_products (ie: tbl_products.Rows.Add(row);). Is this correct? If that's the case, simply clear the existing rows from tbl_products - tbl_products.Rows.Clear(). Add this line as the first line of Load_Products. Does that make sense?

Comment: no.. i commented before that though this would have been a good idea logically , but when dealing with asp pages the change (to the page) would only occure on the page load , when it reads the list 
again and loads the products accordingly.

Comment: @eranotzer: Sorry, I must be misunderstanding something. This is my understanding of your page logic: 1: On the first Page_Load you call Load_Products. 2: The user then interacts with a control that throws the prd_Product_Checked method 3: On postback, you check for Page.IsPostBack and DO NOT reload the control. 4: The prd_Product_Checked method is called and you remove the product from the cart. 5: You then call Load_Products again. Is this correct?

Comment: @eranotzer: Let me know if/when you want to go on chat so we can figure out what the problem is.